# Jquery each loop with delay/interval applying inline style change from array. Looped

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I'm not very good at JavaScript yet I was determined to solve this, however combining infinite loops, with an array and an inline style change with delays has proved beyond my tiny mind.

Essentially I'm trying to build an incredibly lightweight slider/carousel. The slides are lined up horizontally with only one in view. Every couple of seconds the left position on the container changes.

The transitions are done via CSS, so all I need to happen is to loop through an array which contains the left position values applying them sequentially to the container.

I've set up a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/morgyface/nwa4th6f/55/).

This is as far as I've got with the jQuery...

```
function slides() {
    var position = [ "0", "-100%", "-200%", "-300%" ];
    var time = 2000;
    $.each(position, function (index, value) {
        $('.testimonials').css('left', value);
    }, time);
    time += 2000;
}
```

The HTML is this, the container has the class "*testimonials*"

```html
<div>
  <ul class="testimonials" style="left:0">
    <li>We love them. They are super duper.</li>
    <li>They make me feel magical. Like a flying badger.</li>
    <li>At one point they held my organ.</li>
    <li>Cor blimey, what a service they provide.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The values **must come from an array** as this is generated on the fly based on how many slides there are.

It's also important it loops **infinitely**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use recursive functions, here's an example that fits with your code:

```
var position = [ "0", "-100%", "-200%", "-300%" ];
var time = 500;
i=0;
function slides(currentPosition) {
setTimeout(function(){
        $('.testimonials').css('left', currentPosition);
        slides(position[i%position.length])
        console.log(i)
        i++;
        },time)
}
slides(0)
```

but this is only to give you an idea how you can write an infinite loop that animates the slides, of course you need to rearrange it further to obtain the result you want.

Comment: I don't think further rearrangement is necessary? This solves it, the only adjustment I've made is to remove `time += 500;` as this seems to increase the delay on each pass. It's fine if the delay remains constant. Thank you very much for taking the time to respond. The final code is below...

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to @mondersky this seems to be answered. Final code is as follows:

```js
var position = [ "0", "-100%", "-200%", "-300%" ];
var delay = 2000;
i=0;
function slides(currentPosition) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.testimonials').css('left', currentPosition);
    slides(position[i%position.length])
    i++;
  },delay)
}
slides(0)
```